# combineLatest with FormControl valueChanges event binding not emitting

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscribe

I listen to 2 forms via 2 [formControl] "toppings":array and "toppings2":array.

I must have  the 2 values of the forms in the same time. So i combine my two observables with "CombineLatest"

My code:

```
ngOnInit() {
combineLatest(this.toppings.valueChanges, this.toppings2.valueChanges)
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val)) 
}
```

But now, in the initialisation of the component, only one form send console.log(val).

If i click on this form, after i receive log of my second form. Have you meet this problem ?

Comment: So you only get `console.log(val)` if you clicked on both forms at least one time? Remember, that `combineLatest` will not emit an initial value for an observable until each observable emits at least one value.

Comment: yes in the bigining only one form send me valuechanges. If i click on it, the second can send me valuechanges after too.. Just i can't use the second form at first...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You probably want to have an initial value for both Observables. `combineLatest` will only emit if all Observables have emitted at least one value. Use the `startWith` operator to create this behaviour, like this:

```
combineLatest(
  this.toppings.valueChanges.pipe(startWith("")), 
  this.toppings2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(""))
)
```

Or, if you have initial values available, like suggested:

```
combineLatest(
  this.toppings.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.toppings.value)), 
  this.toppings2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.toppings2.value))
)
```

**Note**, that this will emit once with the initial values. To supress this behaviour, you can use the `skip(1)` operator to ignore this initial notification.

Comment: Or `ştartWith(this.toppings.value)`.

Comment: Right, even better

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have an initial value for both Observables. `combineLatest` will only emit if all Observables have emitted at least one value. Use the `startWith` operator to create this behaviour, like this:

```js
combineLatest(
  this.toppings.valueChanges.pipe(startWith("")), 
  this.toppings2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(""))
)
```

Or, if you have initial values available, like suggested:

```js
combineLatest(
  this.toppings.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.toppings.value)), 
  this.toppings2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.toppings2.value))
)
```

Additionally note that this will emit once with the initial values. To supress this behaviour, you can use the `skip(1)` operator to ignore this initial notification.